# Problem with ob_start function in php

Tags: php, html

I have this code, which uses ob_start php function. Which basically puts the echoed data into an html file. It works before. I do not know what version of php I was using then. But my current version is 5.3.0. I cannot explain why it wouldn't work. Because the script below is working and it just puts the output of that script into the html file:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<h2>Customer Payment Summary</h2>
<a href="pdftransactions.php?acts=customerpay&ofile=<?php echo $customer.' customerpay '.$date; ?>"><img id="tablez" src="../img/system/icons/Oficina-PDF-icon.png"></img></a>

<?php
if($amtopay>=$curcred){
    $custchange=$amtopay - $curcred;
    $newcred = 0;

    echo "Change: ". $custchange."<br/>";
    query_database("DELETE  FROM sales_transaction WHERE Cust_Name='$customer'", "onstor", $link);
}else{
    query_database("UPDATE  customer_credit SET CREDIT='$newcred' WHERE Cust_Name='$customer'", "onstor", $link);
    echo "Remaining Balance: ". $newcred."<br/>";;
}

echo "Customer: ".$customer."<br/>";
echo "Amount paid: ". $amtopay. "<br/>";
echo "Date: ". $date." ". date('A');
close_connection($link);
?>

<?php
file_put_contents('../tmp/customerpay.html', ob_get_contents());
?>
```

Here's the output of the code above:
[image]

But when I checked the html file which I specified in the file_put_contents. It gives me this. And I don't really understand why:
[image]

My problem is how to get the correct output from the html file that is being produced.

Comment: So is your problem with the formatting, or the content?

Comment: my problem is with the contents of the html that is being produced.

Comment: Please Add  ob_end_clean(); after the ob_get_contents() statment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't closing your output buffer before you do a file_put_contents...

At the end of your script change it to the following:

```
//...
close_connection($link);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents('../tmp/customerpay.html', $contents);
?>
```

Comment: Also, check your error logs to determine the exact cause of the problem